# add element via js after counting elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This one should be quick. I have a simple page that loads reviews dynamically from a web app which are about 33% wide. the problem is that the reviews are of course all different sizes. What I want to do is to count all the elements with the same class, "reviews", AND to add an element to the page AFTER every third element so I can add a separator, full width, empty div to separate each set of three based on the height of the biggest one in the set. I found a way to count the elements already:

```
var numItems = $('.yourclass').length
```

What I don't know is how to add the separator div after every third element. Here is what each of the elements look like:

```
<div class="one-third column">
<div class="review">
<img alt="" src="{tag_client picture_value}" />
<h3>{tag_client name}</h3>
<p>{tag_client review}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and the link to the page in progress is: http://ladyilgphotography.businesscatalyst.com/reviews

Comment: u already assign i/3 width how can you add frth element

Comment: Jain, i don't know if I understand your comment but i'll give it a shot. The items are being added dynamically through Business Catalyst, but they're being added one by one, not three at a time. I can do three at a time but then I run into responsive issues because of the table that BC sets around the whole thing.

Comment: u have to create a function who reset counter after 3 & when counter reaches to 3 then you have to add separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with jquery, but this should be valid

```
//Document Ready
$(function(){
    var revPerLine = 3;

    $('.review').filter(
        // get every third review by filtering the array
        function(index, elem){return index%revPerLine == (revPerLine-1);}
    ).each(
        // jquery's .after appends a element after the current
        function(index, elem){$(elem).after("<div class='separator'></div>");}
    );
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me which part? the filter/forEach combo, or jquery's after?

Comment: There's no such thing as '.forEach()', just so you know... it's ['.each()'](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: it's giving me an "uncaught type error: undefined is not a function" right after the forEach statement. I uploaded it to the page if you want to look at it.

Comment: Thanks @IndieRok, I really don't know jquery, so I thought $('...') returned an array. In that case, the params should be swapped too

Comment: Okay nvncbl, I changed it after googling the equivalent jquery methods. tested out the code in the console and got new .separator elements!

Comment: thank you @jmullercuber, I have no idea why but it's still not working for me. Any other ideas? Am i missing a silly semi colon?

Comment: Try wrapping jmullercubers's jquery code in the document ready method, which is: $(function(){ //Put code here });

Comment: You want the code to execute when the DOM is ready, aka when the page is fully loaded

Comment: @IndieRok thank you, i had tried that but it did not work. here is the code I have in the body tag:
<script>
$(function(){
var revPerLine = 3;
$('one-third.column.review-wrapper').filter(
// get every third review by filtering the array
function(index, elem){return index%revPerLine == (revPerLine-1);}
).each(
// jquery's .after appends a element after the current
function(index, elem){$(elem).after("<div class='full-width'>&nbsp;</div>");}
);});
</script>

Comment: Gosh darn it!! Never mind, i had $('one-third.column.review-wrapper') instead of $('.one-third.column.review-wrapper') ...

Comment: Thank you guys for your patience! I appreciate it a ton. If you want to help me figure out a silly facebook og issue, go here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216136/1x1-px-og-image-facebook

Comment: No problem! I do have another little fix for you if you don't mind. Change the css display property of your '.review' class from block to inline-block. This will fix the text from going into your footer, as it happens right now (see rebecca's super long text when the browser's width is about 958px)

Comment: @IndieRok thank you i appreciate all the advice you can give me. Actually the reason why you saw that overlap is because before your solution i had to set a hard height, which was too long for all the reviews except for that one, but now with the separator and a height of auto on each, we are money. Thanks again

Comment: Indeed, you're right! My bad, I forgot to hard refresh the page to empty the cache. Well I'm glad I could of help